# Shared memory | Node.JS + PHP | blocksize | remove trailing "00"

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, shared-memory

I am using shared memory to make data available among a PHP and a Node.JS process (on Debian9). I Open the memory block on php with shmop_open(). That function requires the size in bytes of the memory block. Since the block is created once and then repeating filled with differnt sized data, i select block size with a little buffer space. That means the block size can´t be as big as the data size, since it changes often. Data written with shmop_write() is of type string btw.

In Node.JS i use the module shm-typed-array to access the shm. I use shm.get (key, 'Buffer'). After that i convert it into a string using toString('utf8').

The Problem: shm.get() reads the entire shared memory, no matter how many bytes are actually used. So i receive a hexadecimal which is followed by a lot of 00 pairs. If i convert that hexa into a string, i receive my previosuly saved data with a lot of (spaces?) behind it. How am i supposed to fix this? I cannot "trim()" the resulting string, which makes me guess those spaces behind my data are no "real" spaces.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i would slice from zero to the first index of the delimter

Comment: @dandavis What kind of delimiter? Should i create one myself and append it to the string before i save the data with PHP?